# Creating structures with references in Rust

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and I have been trying to start solving some optimization problems using it. My goal is to parse an instance (in this case a JSON string) containing information about the entities of the problem. After parsing the instance, I would have a struct containing all the different types of entities read.

In the following code, I have managed to read the JSON string and iterate over some entities. I tried to implement the trait `From` so that it could convert from a `serde_json::Map` to an `Entity`.

```rust
use serde_json::{Map, Value};
use std::{collections::HashSet};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Entity<'a> {
    field1: u64,
    field2: &'a str,
}

impl <'a> Entity<'a> {
    fn read_entities(json_entities: &Value) -> HashSet<Entity> {
        let mut entities = HashSet::new();

        if json_entities.is_array() {
            let array = json_entities.as_array().unwrap();
            for item in array.iter() {
                entities.insert(Entity::from(item));
            }
        }

        entities
    }
}

impl <'a> From<&Map<String, Value>> for Entity<'a> {
    fn from(obj: &Map<String, Value>) -> Entity<'a> {
        Entity {
            field1: obj["Field1"].as_u64().unwrap(),
            field2: obj["Field2"].as_str().unwrap(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Data<'a> {
    entities: HashSet<Entity<'a>>,
}

impl <'a> Data<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Data<'a> {
        let data = r#"{"Entities":[{"Field1":0,"Field2":"Abc"},{"Field1":1,"Field2":"Abc"}]}"#;
        let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("");
        let mut entities = Entity::read_entities(&json["Entities"]);
        Data {
            entities,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = Data::new();
}
```

I have struggled with the following two errors:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Entity<'_>: From<&Value>` is not satisfied
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
```

My understanding from the first error is that the trait I have implemented is for `Entity<'a>` and thus the compiler cannot call `Entity::from(item)`. However, I could not figure out where I should inform the lifetime `'a` of `Entity` in this call. I feel that the second error is a similar problem regarding where I should place the lifetime `'a`. I have struggled with both errors for a while, but I could not figure out on my own.

I would also be very glad if you could point out if anything is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with the posted code, but mostly it boils down to one root cause.

Passing lifetimes about and using `&str` for fields would be appropriate if you are trying to get every bit of performance that you can from the code. But in this case, it is hindering you - and the JSON types don't allow for it anyway - the `Value` enum actually contains a `String` rather than a `&str`, which I believe is because of the JSON string escaping rules.

The reason you have got the `<'a>` everywhere is because you're using `&str` in `Entity`, rather than `String`.

The next issue is that your `From` is taking a `&Map<String, Value>`, not `&Value`.

Making these two changes I get:

```
use serde_json::Value;
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Entity {
    field1: u64,
    field2: String,
}

impl Entity {
    fn read_entities(json_entities: &Value) -> HashSet<Entity> {
        let mut entities = HashSet::new();

        if json_entities.is_array() {
            let array = json_entities.as_array().unwrap();
            for item in array.iter() {
                entities.insert(Entity::from(item));
            }
        }

        entities
    }
}

impl From<&Value> for Entity {
    fn from(obj: &Value) -> Entity {
        Entity {
            field1: obj["Field1"].as_u64().unwrap(),
            field2: obj["Field2"].as_str().unwrap().to_string(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Data {
    entities: HashSet<Entity>,
}

impl Data {
    pub fn new() -> Data {
        let data = r#"{"Entities":[{"Field1":0,"Field2":"Abc"},{"Field1":1,"Field2":"Abc"}]}"#;
        let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("");
        let entities = Entity::read_entities(&json["Entities"]);
        Data { entities }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = Data::new();
}
```

which you can find on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82c64ae49f6b76cb5ed72db3d68af385)

Comment: My understanding is that your solution only works for strings. Ultimately, I would like to have references to structs in my Entity. Field2 could be a reference to a different entity type. For example, I could parse a list of brands and items from my JSON string, and each item would have a reference to a brand. In this case, how should I proceed? I can update my question, if needed.